# converting json Array into Json object and adding more items to it on MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, json, database, group-by

In a MySQL table how do i convert the values of a column which currently holds JSON array values to an array of JSON objects using the previous values ?

current column( contains only IDs):

```
items
-------

[1,2,3]
[2,3]
...
```

required format:

```
items
-------

[ { id:1, lastUpdatedBy:"", timeStamp:"--" },{ id:2, lastUpdatedBy:"", timeStamp:"--" },{ id:3, lastUpdatedBy:"", timeStamp:"--" }]
[  { id:2, lastUpdatedBy:"", timeStamp:"--" },{ id:3, lastUpdatedBy:"", timeStamp:"--" }]
...
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are running MySQL 8.0, you can unnest the array with `json_table()`, and then build json objects and aggregate with `json_arrayagg()`.

For this to work, you need a primary key - I assumed `pk`:

```
select json_arrayagg(json_object(
    'id', i.id, 
    'lastUpdatedBy', 12, 
    'timestamp', '--'
)) items
from mytable t
cross join json_table(t.items, '$[*]' columns (id int path '$')) i 
group by t.pk
```

If you want an `update` query:

```
update mytable t
inner join (
    select json_arrayagg(json_object(
        'id', i.id, 
        'lastUpdatedBy', 12, 
        'timestamp', '--'
    )) items
    from mytable t
    cross join json_table(t.items, '$[*]' columns (id int path '$')) i 
    group by t.pk
) x on x.pk = t.pk
set x.items = t.items
```

Comment: thank you for the answer , @GMB. How do i replace the old column with this this newly obtained column in the original table with correct mapping with the PK though?

Comment: tried this, but since PK is not in table x, i get the error: Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'x.pk' in 'on clause'

Comment: @BlackJack: obviously you need to replace `pk`with the actual name of the primary key column of your table.